# RestSharp AddBody adding double quote in JSON parameter

Tags: c#, json, web-services, restsharp

I am calling API with RESTSharp

```
  var client = new RestClient("http://demoservice.com");
  var request = new RestRequest("callapi", "put");          
  request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

string jsonaction = "{\"tokenid\":\"x123x45\",\"userid\":\"2456\",\"ip\":\"192.168.1.20\",\"transaction\":\"6\",\"actionCode\":\"78\",\"jtoken\":\"systemtoken\"}";
request.AddBody(new { action = "SAVE", data = "savedata", token = "systemtoken", jsonaction = jsonaction });
```

I am checking in debug data passing in request. and my expected output as follows

```
{"action":"SAVE","data":"savedata","token":"systemtoken","jsonaction":{"tokenid":"x123x45","userid":"2456","ip":"192.168.1.20","transaction":"6","actionCode":"78","jtoken":"systemtoken"}}
```

But getting

```
{"action":"SAVE","data":"savedata","token":"systemtoken","jsonaction":"{"tokenid":"x123x45","userid":"2456","ip":"192.168.1.20","transaction":"6","actionCode":"78","jtoken":"systemtoken"}"}
```

If anybody can guide how to post for JSON I have tried with Addbody and AddJsonBody but nothing works.

Comment: if you want the jsonobject to be taken as a string, simply change it to
`string jsonAction = "\"{\"tokenid\":\"x123x45\",\"userid\":\"2456\",\"ip\":\"192.168.1.20\",\"transaction\":\"6\",\"actionCode\":\"78\",\"jtoken\":\"systemtoken\"}\"";`

Comment: That is also tried. also tried to save json as temp.json and using File.ReadAllText pass all data but everytime it appends " in jsonaction

Comment: @KetanKotak, I Added my answer below try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can do this using the `request.AddParameter()` method:

```
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("application/json", data , ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

Where data is of the format:

```
data :

{
  "action":"dosomething" ,
  "data":"somedata" ,
  "token":"sometoken",
  "jsonAction": {
    "tokenId": "",
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: OP want to send Body with Request not Parameter.

Comment: @er-sho one can use AddParameter method also to take essential control of the body>> SEE: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest  `RequestBody:
If this parameter is set, its value will be sent as the body of the request. Only one RequestBody parameter is accepted - the first one.`

Comment: And in same link its also said that => `It is recommended to use AddJsonBody or AddXmlBody methods instead of AddParameter with type BodyParameter. Those methods will set the proper request type and do the serialization work for you.`

Comment: Yes, but here the OP has already serialized the json in his code, that's why I have suggested the `AddParameter` method and it satisfies your first comment right? It works and it is one of the possible methods to make a request!

Comment: Its not the issue that OP serialized the json or not. Providing the best solution to problem is all maaters and what if json not been serialized then what happens with `AddParamter`?

Comment: Not to argue, but *"That Serialization"* itself is the problem here!

Comment: This is not the arguments between both of us. This is the way to improve our kowlegde. Anyways all the best for your answer :)

Comment: I don't know what was exactly issue but .AddBody was not working while .AddParameter("application/json",data , ParameterType.RequestBody); worked perfectly. I could post request successfully. Thank a ton

Comment: @er-sho Thank for your help and guidance. I could create data because of your JObject Method only

Comment: @KetanKotak, So which answer was solved your problem?

Comment: @er-sho You should undelete your answer, it was a valid one. This is one of the possible ways, and so is yours

Comment: combination of both worked. JObject jObject = new JObject(); I never thought to do. that's why a special thanks to you. I can mark your answer as accepted solution if you undelete.

Comment: @kowsikbabu, glad to hear from you. but I think my answer doesn't resolved OP problem. But your's do. :)

Comment: I tried to request.AddParameter but I was posting individual one. so I didn't try @kowsikbabu answer by assuming it was already tried. but later on I got that I can pass parameter as "application/json" and ParameterType.RequestBody so that logic from his answer and data was prepared using your answer

Comment: @KetanKotak, No any problem that you accept or unaccept my answer but I really glad that your problem has been resolved now and all the best for you :)

Comment: I spent 2 days behind such code. though it was of few lines but was unaware of the same.

Comment: @KetanKotak, your thankfull words is important for me than accepting an answer :)

Comment: Please undelete your post so other can take reference of the same.

Comment: @KetanKotak, from you insist, I undelete my answer but you keep **kausikbabu** answer accepted

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use `JObject` to create your body for a request like,

```
JObject jObject = new JObject();
jObject["action"] = "SAVE";
jObject["data"] = "savedata";
jObject["token"] = "systemtoken";
jObject["jsonaction"] = JObject.Parse("{\"tokenid\":\"x123x45\",\"userid\":\"2456\",\"ip\":\"192.168.1.20\",\"transaction\":\"6\",\"actionCode\":\"78\",\"jtoken\":\"systemtoken\"}");
```

And then pass this `jObject` to either

```
request.AddBody(jObject.ToString());
```

OR

```
request.AddJsonBody(jObject.ToString());
```

And for `JObject` you need to import `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` namespace to your program and you can find this namespace in `newtonsoft.json` package.

You can even use like this

```
request.AddBody(new { action = "SAVE", data = "savedata", token = "systemtoken", jsonaction = JObject.Parse(jsonaction) });
```

But creating a JObject for your full json data is best that minimizes the error and exception while creating own json data with string

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I tried it creates perfect jObject but when I post it shows [[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]]

Comment: show me how you implemented my answer to your side. add your code in your post

Comment: string jsonaction = "{\"tokenid\":\"x123x45\",\"userid\":\"2456\",\"ip\":\"192.168.1.20\",\"transaction\":\"6\",\"actionCode\":\"78\",\"jtoken\":\"systemtoken\"}";

Comment: JObject jObject = new JObject();
            jObject["action"] = "Save";
            jObject["data"] = "savedata";
            jObject["token"] = "systemtoken";
            jObject["jsonaction"] = JObject.Parse(Regex.Replace(jsonaction, @"\s+", ""));

Comment: request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            //            request.AddJsonBody(new { action = "SAVE", data = "savedata", token:"systemtoken", jsonaction = JObject.Parse(Regex.Replace(jsonaction, @"\s+", ""))});
            request.AddJsonBody(jObject);

Comment: Why you add this Regex.Replace method?

Comment: when I watch jObject it shows perfect json as I want. but request.AddBody(jObject) showing [],[],[],[] only

Comment: remove that Regex.Replace part from and just use it like => `jsonaction = JObject.Parse(jsonaction)`

Comment: to remove white space from string

Comment: Its automatically remove when you use `JObject`

Comment: ok tried. only in Watch.. jObject showing full JSON but after adding to request request.AddJsonBody(jObject); when I watch tit shows [[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]]

Comment: And what about with `request.AddBody(jObject)`?

Comment: Ok try to add `ToString()` to either AddBody or AddJsonBody like `request.AddBody(jObject.ToString())` or ``request.AddJsonBody(jObject.ToString())``

Comment: nops. even I tried string sObject = jObject.ToString(); I can get sObject as perfect one but request.AddJsonBody(sObject) or request.AddBody(sObject) doesn't work. I don't know why. it keep saying missing parameter. while I copy sObject data to postman and post it works fine

Comment: Whats acually it says `missing paramter` could you please copy error or excpetion here

Comment: on server side I had asked team they saying they don't get jsonaction in request. while my sObject showing {"action":"SAVE","data":"savedata","token":"systemtoken","jsonaction":{"tokenid":"x123x45","userid":"2456","ip":"192.168.1.20","transaction":"6","actionCode":"78","jtoken":"systemtoken"}}

Comment: Use like this then => `request.AddBody(new { action = "SAVE", data = "savedata", token = "systemtoken", jsonaction = JObject.Parse(jsonaction).ToString() });`

Comment: only add  ToString after `JObject.Parse(jsonaction)`

Answer (score 0):

From two genius people I could complete following code

```
jsonaction objjsonaction = new jsonaction();
            objjsonaction.tokenid = "x123x45";
            objjsonaction.userid = "2456";
            objjsonaction.ip = "192.168.1.20";
            objjsonaction.transaction = "6";
            objjsonaction.actionCode = "78";
            objjsonaction.jtoken = gentoken("key"); // gentoken() is external function for generating token from key

string sobjjsonaction = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objjsonaction);
            sobjjsonaction = sobjjsonaction.Replace("__", "-");

            JObject jObject = new JObject();
            jObject["action"] = "SAVE";
            jObject["data"] = getpostdata(); // a function to generate data from db
            jObject["token"] = gentoken("key"); // gentoken() is external function for generating token from key
            jObject["jsonaction"] = JObject.Parse(sobjjsonaction);

            string sObject = Regex.Replace(jObject.ToString(), @"\s+", "");

            //request.Method = Method.PUT;
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.Parameters.Clear();
            request.AddParameter("application/json", sObject, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```